Künneth formula for bounded flat complexes
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $X_\bullet, Y_\bullet$ be bounded chain complexes consisting out of flat modules. Does it hold that
$$ \bigoplus_{i + j = n} H^n (X_i) \otimes H^n(Y_j) = H^n(X_\bullet \otimes Y_\bullet)? $$

This holds if you're over a nice ring, where submodules of flat modules are flat, e.g. a principal ideal domain; you're also missing a torsion term, there's a Kunneth short exact sequence usually. See the list of theorems here for more generalities, but mind that many of those theorems have hypotheses on the ring! If you happen to know the bound on your complexes and the global dimension of your ring (if it is finite), you might also get mileage out of the Kunneth spectral sequence

"Foxby, Bounded complexes of flat modules" might help. Never read it myself, just saw it now mentioned in another MSE post
